# Flutter: "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a photo gallery app in flutter but I have this error "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found" when I do await _controller.takePicture(**path**);
Can anyone tell me how I can fix this.

```
void _takePicture() async {
    try {
        await _initializeControllerFuture;

        final tmpDirectory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
        final filePath = '${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.png';
        final path = join(tmpDirectory.path, filePath);

        await _controller.takePicture(path);

        widget.didProvideImagePath(path);
    } catch (e) {
        print(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show what's inside didProvideImagePath?

Answer (score 0):

If it says it does not accepts parameters just call the method as is:

```
widget.didProvideImagePath();
```

Comment: sorry it's not widget.didProvideImagePath(path); that I get error. It was the line above that I get an error which is await _controller.takePicture(path);. do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Take a look at which parameters does that function accepts. At least they are not positional so it maybe takes no parameters at all `_controller.takePicture()` or named parameters. But the function definition would be needed to check that